# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jep in java.library.path

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have 'libjep.so' file after downloading jep and I also had set the environmental variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `~./bashrc` as shown below:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jep/libjep.so
```

as  well as in runtime

```
System.load("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jep/libjep.so");
```

But when I have the follwing line in my code,

```
Jep jep = new Jep();
```

It shows the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jep in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at jep.Jep$TopInterpreter$1.run(Jep.java:118)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the directory containing your library, and not your library itself like this

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jep/
```

You can also try adding this argument to the java command when you start your java application so java can find the library

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jep/
```

Comment: I have tried your solution by adding it into the java argument, however, the error message now is: Exception in thread "main" jep.JepException: <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named jep

Comment: @JonathanLiono That error typically indicates that you have more than one python installed on your system and the libpython.so being used is part of a python that does not have jep installed. Try adding the location of the correct libpython to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_PRELOAD

Comment: It's correct. But you need to execute your code including the jep-3.8.2.jar file. For example: java -classpath /path/to/jar/jep-3.8.2.jar -jar foo.jar

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` occurs only when if the required library is not in the path or it is already loaded.
Couple of things you need to make sure is :

1) You're performing `System.load(....)` inside static block so that its executed only once.
2) Also, you can try removing extension.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Still, anyway I set that in LD_LIBRARY_PATH then why it is showing the error?