# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jep.Jep.init(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;ZZ) on google cloud dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, jep

Firstly I don't understand why people put negative score on this question. Either explain how can I improve question. I can further elaborate. This is a feedback form my side. Though I am new but I have no intention to ask question without putting my efforts.

I am trying to run spark job written in Scala on Google Cloud Platform Dataproc cluster which uses jep interpreter.

I have added jep as dependency.

Whats the full short solution to run jep on Scala using Google Cloud Platform Dataproc

```
"black.ninia" % "jep" % "3.9.0"
```

in my install.sh script  I have written

```
sudo -E pip install jep    
export JEP_PATH=$(pip show jep | grep "^Location:" | cut -d ':' -f 2,3 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$JEP_PATH/jep
```

Still I am getting the below error (no jep in java.library.path)

```
20/01/07 09:07:23 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 74, fs-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-test-w-1.c.xx-xxxx.internal, executor 1): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jep in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at jep.MainInterpreter.initialize(MainInterpreter.java:128)
    at jep.MainInterpreter.getMainInterpreter(MainInterpreter.java:101)
    at jep.Jep.<init>(Jep.java:256)
    at jep.SharedInterpreter.<init>(SharedInterpreter.java:56)
    at dunnhumby.sciencebank.SubsCommons$$anonfun$getUnitVecEmbeddings$1.apply(SubsCommons.scala:33)
    at dunnhumby.sciencebank.SubsCommons$$anonfun$getUnitVecEmbeddings$1.apply(SubsCommons.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

(edited):-

1.) I have seen specific answers to on premises machine but not for Google Cloud Platform.

2.) I found https://github.com/ninia/jep/issues/141 but this did not help

3.) I also found [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183062/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-jep-in-java-librar) but that is not answered and that's not accepted for Google Cloud Platform as well. And I have even performed all steps from there.

4.) If question is missing some snapshots I ll attach . But please provide some comments.

(Edited:- 08012020 I am adding install.sh used )

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x -e

# Disable ipv6 since it seems to cause intermittent SocketTimeoutException when collecting data
# See CENG-1268 in Jira
printf "\nnet.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1\nnet.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1\n" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p

if [[ $(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/dataproc-role) == Master ]]; then
    config_bucket="$(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/dataproc-cluster-configuration-directory | cut -d'/' -f3)"
    dataproc_cluster_name="$(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/dataproc-cluster-name)"
    hdfs dfs -mkdir -p gs://${config_bucket}/${dataproc_cluster_name}/spark_events
    systemctl restart spark-history-server.service
fi

tee -a /etc/hosts << EOM
$$(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value /attributes/preprod-mjr-dataplatform-metrics-mig-ip) influxdb
EOM

echo "[global]
index-url = https://cs-anonymous:XXXXXXXX@artifactory.xxxxxxxx.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-remote/simple" >/etc/pip.conf

PIP_REQUIREMENTS_FILE=gs://preprod-xxx-dpl-artif/dataproc/requirements.txt
PIP_TRANSITIVE_REQUIREMENTS_FILE=gs://preprod-xxx-dpl-artif/dataproc/transitive-requirements.txt

gsutil cp ${PIP_REQUIREMENTS_FILE} .
gsutil cp ${PIP_TRANSITIVE_REQUIREMENTS_FILE} .
gsutil -q cp gs://preprod-xxx-dpl-artif/dataproc/apt-transport-https_1.4.8_amd64.deb /tmp/apt-transport-https_1.4.8_amd64.deb

export http_proxy=http://preprod-xxx-securecomms.preprod-xxx-securecomms.il4.us-east1.lb.dh-xxxxx-media-55595.internal:3128
export https_proxy=http://preprod-xxx-securecomms.preprod-xxx-securecomms.il4.us-east1.lb.dh-xxxxx-media-55595.internal:3128
export no_proxy=google.com,googleapis.com,localhost
echo "deb https://cs-anonymous:Welcome123@artifactory.xxxxxxxx.com/artifactory/debian-main-remote stretch main" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/main.list
echo "deb https://cs-anonymous:Welcome123@artifactory.xxxxxxxx.com/artifactory/maria-db-debian stretch main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/main.list
echo 'Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order:: "gz";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02update
echo 'Acquire::http::Timeout "10";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99timeout
echo 'Acquire::ftp::Timeout "10";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99timeout
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/apt-transport-https_1.4.8_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated -y /tmp/apt-transport-https_1.4.8_amd64.deb
sudo -E apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated -y -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="sources.list.d/main.list" -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts="-" -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup="0"

sudo -E apt-get --allow-unauthenticated -y install python-pip gcc python-dev python-tk curl
#requires index-url specifying because the version of pip installed by previous command
#installs an old version that doesn't seem to recognise pip.conf
sudo -E pip install --index-url https://cs-anonymous:xxxxxxx@artifactory.xxxxxxxx.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-remote/simple --ignore-installed pip setuptools wheel

sudo -E pip install jep

sudo -E pip install gensim

JEP_PATH=$(pip show jep | grep "^Location:" | cut -d ':' -f 2,3 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

cat << EOF >> /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$JEP_PATH/jep
export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:$JEP_PATH/jep
EOF

tee -a /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf << EOM
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$JEP_PATH/jep
export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:$JEP_PATH/jep
EOM

tee -a /etc/*bashrc << EOM
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$JEP_PATH/jep
export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:$JEP_PATH/jep
EOM

source /etc/*bashrc

sudo -E apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated -y \
  pkg-config \
  freetype* \
  python-matplotlib \
  libpq-dev \
  libssl-dev \
  libcrypto* \
  python-dev \
  libtext-csv-xs-perl \
  libmysqlclient-dev \
  libfreetype* \
  libzmq3-dev \
  libzmq3*


sudo -E pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

Comment: What was the full command you used to create the Dataproc cluster?

Comment: Actually thats a big file and many things are specific to our organization. So I cant put full of it here. However, If you need I can reply with specific lins or conf as you ask

Comment: we are creating cluster using Scala based API call

Comment: One important thing we need is whether you used init actions like the "conda" init action, jupyter, and/or used --optional-components with jupyter. These things will change the python envs and in general, the "default" python install for a logged-in user might not be the same python install used by Spark executors or Spark drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using install.sh as an init action for Dataproc, your `export` commands would only export those environment variables in the local shell session running the init action, not persistently for all Spark processes that run thereafter.

The way to have Spark use custom environment variables is to add them to `/etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh`. Here's a [spark user discussion about how to set java.library.path in Spark](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-set-java-library-path-in-a-spark-cluster-td13854.html).

---

Essentially you can just use a heredoc in your init action around the parts that export environment variables. However, as shown in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1719 the environment variable won't be sufficient to propagate the library path into the executors in YARN; spark [explicitly sets the library path](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/ExecutorRunnable.scala#L147) rather than propagating through `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so we must use `spark.executor.extraLibraryPath` as well in `spark-defaults.conf`

```
JEP_PATH=$(pip show jep | grep "^Location:" | cut -d ':' -f 2,3 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

# spark-env.sh for driver process.
cat << EOF >> /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
# Note that backslash before $LD_LIBRARY_PATH on the right hand side;
# it is important that the variable is evaluated in spark-env.sh rather
# than clobbering it with the local $LD_LIBRARY_PATH of the init action
# running process.
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$JEP_PATH/jep
EOF

# For executor processes
cat << EOF >> /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath=$JEP_PATH/jep
EOF
```

Comment: Hi @Dennis, I tried performing suggested things as  below but still getting the same error.      
 JEP_PATH=$(pip show jep | grep "^Location:" | cut -d ':' -f 2,3 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

cat << EOF >> /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$JEP_PATH/jep
export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:$JEP_PATH/jep
EOF

Comment: Could you check what actually ended up in the spark-env.sh file? I think the problem might be that you actually need to escape the '$' in the heredoc because we might not want the export to be the literal that gets resolve at the time the init script runs, but rather to have the environment variable reference from inside the spark-env file. You did the right thing extracting the JEP_PATH= part outside of the heredoc, i'll also up date my answer.

Comment: Okay I did more digging and it looks like LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't actually make it into Spark executors in YARN. Updating my answer now. Note that you probably don't need the LD_PRELOAD and also, you shouldn't cat the environment variable lines into `spark-defaults.conf` because `spark-defaults.conf` is a different properties format than spark-env.sh.